# How to automate git version release of master branch?

Tags: git

I was looking for a way to automate the process of updating my master branch (the released version) for a project.

Basically only two branches will exist on the origin repository (develop and master...  possibly more when hotfixes or specific develop branches come up).

However, running through all the commands in the nvie article (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) was error prone when farmed out to multiple potential maintainers.

To alleviate the issue of possible typos in version naming conventions, and to make the process consistent and reliable across all maintainers I wanted to write a script to verify the input.

Comment: Well now, that was a quick downvote.  How can I improve this to win your support?

Comment: You have a good overview in the body, but you do not state the question in the body (I realise it is in the title) - but maybe cleanup the body to be clear on what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow

That’s a set of scripts that handle all the stuff required for the git flow model.

Comment: Gitflow is useful, but I felt like it adds too much complexity for "simple" projects with only a handful of developers.  Maybe I'll write up a script to automate some if its features for my project.

Comment: I have completely changed my mind after the requirements for the project decided to grow into a larger project...

Answer (score 5):

Here is my `bump.sh` script that I call and I give it a new version to update to.  It takes care of MOST of the rest of the process.

`me@server:~/git_repos/# ./bump.sh git_project`

```
Enter new version (Current 1.0.5): 1.0.6
Are you sure you want to release version 1.0.6? (y|n): y
Switched to a new branch 'release-1.0.6'
Switched to branch 'master'
Deleted branch release-1.0.6 (was 4abcd98e).

If you need to undo this last commit, abort now and run:
  git reset --hard HEAD~1
  git tag -d 1.0.6

Do you want to push this to the origin server (THIS IS NOT EASILY UNDONE)? (y|n): y
Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org':
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 704 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: bb/acl: user is allowed. accepted payload.
To https://remote_repository.../.git
   ffffffab..010101ab  master -> master
Finished merging.
```

`bump.sh`

```
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "Must pass git directory as the first argument."
    exit 2;
fi

cd $1
echo -e "Enter new version (Current `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`): \c "
while read ver; do
    if ([[ ! -z "$ver" ]]) && ([ "$ver" == "`echo $ver | grep "^[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\}$"`" ])
    then
        break
    else
        echo "  Version entered ($ver) was not formatted properly."
        echo -e "Enter new version (Current `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`): \c "
    fi
done

echo -e "Are you sure you want to release version $ver? (y|n): \c "
read confirm

if([ $confirm == "y" ]) then
    git checkout -b release-$ver develop
    git checkout master
    result=`git merge --no-ff release-$ver`
    if([ "$result" == "`echo $result | grep "^Already up-to-date\."`" ]) then
        git branch -D release-$ver
        echo "The branch is already up to date.  Aborting version bump.";
        exit 3;
    else
        git tag -a $ver -m "Used bump script."
        git branch -D release-$ver
        echo ""
        echo "If you need to undo this last commit, abort now and run:"
        echo "  git reset --hard HEAD~1"
        echo "  git tag -d $ver"
        echo ""
        echo -e "Push this change to the origin server and merge back into the develop branch? (y|n): \c "
        read confirm 
        if([ $confirm == "y" ]) then
            git push origin master
            git checkout develop
            git merge master
        fi

        echo "Finished merging."
        exit 1;
    fi
else
    echo "Aborted the version bump."
    exit 1;
fi
```